# Java: 10gb database read into array list means 10gb worth of memory?

Tags: java, database, memory

Sorry if the title is not clear.

If i read 10gb worth of data from a database into a List, does that mean the application is now consuming 10gb worth of memory? Or is there some type of optimisation/compression involved?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, if you read 10GB worth of data into any program all at once it will result in greater than 10GB memory being used due to overhead of objects. From experience this amplification factor is around 2.4 ~ 3x (i.e 10GB = 24 ~ 30GB of memory being consumed).

When dealing with large amounts of memory, process a small block and write it to your output. This way, you do not load all 10GB at once, thus saving memory.

If your 10GB database is required to respond to queries submitted to it. Only fetch the data when the query is submitted and use caching to optimize the database. Impose a maximum results set size limit to prevent your program from running into a OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: I see - thank you. I had hoped the opposite would be true.. I need the entire database to perform my calcuations. So the output is nonsensical for only blocks at a time. Do i need to change my calculations to be able to perform them incrementally or is there a better way?

Comment: @Max Is there no way you can store partial calculations? For example, to sum a particular field in the database only requires you to load one entry (row) at once whilst maintaining a summation variable. Of course, the complexity of your calculations may extend far beyond simple summation, but I believe there will always be a way to allow only a subset of the database to be read at any given time.

Comment: perhaps you can look at an inmemory cache like redis.

Comment: Thanks CPU Terminator. I think the short term answer is to build it and see how we go. Selective querying will probably be a longer term solution.